# Dynamics CRM: Xrm.Internal.openDialog() Cancel Button Callback

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog, dynamics-crm, xrm

I have got a custom Dialog (web ressource) which i open with window.open over a ribbon button.

In this custom Dialog i open the crm lookupdialog with window.open. If the user clicks OK, i can set the Dialog window focused.

I want to focus the dialog window, when the user clicks Cancel.
Can anyone help me please?

```
DialogOption.width = 500; DialogOption.height = 600;
var dialogWindow = this.crmWindow.Xrm.Internal.openDialog(lookupurl, DialogOption, null, null, (returnValue) => this.ngZone.run(() => {
    this.lookupId = returnValue.items[0].id;
    this.lookupText = returnValue.items[0].name;
    window.focus();
  }));
```

Comment: Using Internal method is unsupported. Which crm version?

Comment: I know that it is unsupported :)
crm-version: 8.2